# How to set file destination in React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, react-typescript

I'm following up on this article to download objects from GCP Cloud storage bucket: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-nodejs In the code, I want to set the destination where file needs to be saved dynamically. How can I set file destination in React?

Comment: `destFileName` in the documentation is just a variable. Set this value to whatever you want. If you aren't sure how to do this, can you include what you've attempted?

Comment: You can instruct the API to set the download destination as @kingkupps said. Meanwhile, you should reconsider your design as allowing users to choose a storage file is likely to be a flaw.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure. As per my understanding that variable refers to file path where the objects needs to be saved. How can I capture file path in react?

Comment: @tmarwen How can I set the download destination using React?

Comment: Is the issue that your code is running in the browser and doesn't have "arbitrary access" to write to your local file system behind the browser?  If yes, then the you are likely going to want to use GCS API to access/stream the GCS data and write to a browser selected target file.

Comment: @Kolban My issue is the GCS API to download objects requires a destination path to save a file. I'm not sure how to set that path in React (Client side) . I tried searching on GCS docs but coudn't find anything helpful.

Comment: @KillMe - My guess ... is that you can't.  The GCS API is "node JS" API which typically means server side code.  I get the impression that you want to get a GCS object's data (client side) and then write that to a local file (on the browser/client).  Can you confirm?  If yes, then I think we are going to have to look for a solution where you open the GCS file for reading and use browser API to write locally a selected file from the browser.   Can you clarify WHERE you want the file written?  On the browser machine or on a remote server?

Comment: Yes @Kolban I want to write that object to a local file (on the browser/client).

Comment: I like the story and may have a go at building a sample.  So that a sample matches what you want, can you explain how you see it being used?  I'm imagining a user selecting an object on GCS.  This could be manual selection or the app just "knowing" which file.  I'm then imagining the user being prompted for where to save this file locally.  I don't believe that the rules of HTML "just allow" a file to be saved without a user explicitly saying "HERE".  Would this match your desires?

Comment: Thanks & Yes @Kolban, the user flow you mentioned would work for me!

Comment: I got to thinking about this puzzle some more ... the links we have been using are for NodeJS libraries ... but NodeJS is server side code.  I think what you want to look at is using "Google's Firebase" storage access.  This is the recipe to access Google object storage from a browser ... see ... https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage

Answer (score 0):

just set desFileName:

```
const destFileName = '/local/path/to/file.txt';    
async function downloadFile() {
      const options = {
        destination: destFileName,
      };
    
      // Downloads the file
      await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).download(options);
    
      console.log(
        `gs://${bucketName}/${fileName} downloaded to ${destFileName}.`
      );
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure. As per my understanding that variable refers to file path where the objects needs to be saved. How can I capture file path in react?